# Uniqueness of extension of the normed space structure to a larger topological space

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

The following popped up when I was contemplating the completion of normed linear spaces.

**Question:** Let $E$ be an NLS (normed linear space) and $X$ a topological space. Let $E$ sit inside $X$ as a dense subset. Under what conditions can one ensure that there exists *at most one* NLS structure on $X$ that extends that on $E$?

##### Thoughts

1. If I demand that $X$ is a complete metric space with
   $$
   d(x, y) = \| x - y\|\tag{1}
   $$
   for $x, y\in E$, then the above does hold with many more consequences: There exists a unique Banach space structure on $X$ that extends the NLS structure of $E$ . However, I am wondering about weakening this seemingly stringent condition (1).
2. Say $X$ does admit an NLS structure that extends that on $E$. Then $X$ gets another topology from this extended norm. *If this new topology coincides with $X$'s original topology*, then $E$ is dense in the NLS $X$ as well. Now, the fact that continuous functions on a Hausdorff space are determined by their values on a dense subset of the domain, we can conclude that addition, scalar multiplication and norm (all continuous) are determined uniquely, as desired. <s>Note that this also implies that $X$'s original topology came from a metric satisfying (1).</s>

---

**Edit:** I have managed to show the following:

> **Result**. Let $E$ be an NLS that is contained in a complete metric space $X$ as a dense subset with its norm being uniformly equivalent to the metric inherited from $X$. Then there's a unique Banach space structure on $X$, topologically equivalent to the original metric on $X$, that extends the NLS structure on $E$. Further, the extended norm is uniformly related to the original metric on $X$ in the same way as the original norm was to the restricted metric on $E$.

Comment: This question  only makes sense if $X$ is a topological vector space.

Comment: @PaulFrost Why so? I am explicitly asking whether $X$ can be equipped with an NLS structure that complies with that of $E$.